# How to debug when added MIME Type is not working on IIS for .Net Core projects

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, mime-types

When I refer to an `".apk"` file in the browser whether it be `http` or `https` response is `error 404` and it don't start to download that file.

The address of `".apk"` is
`http://example.com/Upload/App/a.apk` and to verify that I'm pointing to correct address I've placed a picture file in that location (`http://example.com/Upload/App/a.png`) and I could open the picture by browser.

I've searched over stackoverflow and google and tried everything on several first pages but all of them are providing the same contents and while the provided solution is working for everyone it doesn't work for me.

---

### What I've tried:

I've done this steps as provided in all articles, questions, documentations:

1. In `IIS` manager I've selected website and clicked on `MIME Types`
2. I've clicked on `Add` hyper link and defined a new `MIME Type`
3. Values are `".apk"` for extention and `"application/vnd.android.package-archive"` for MIME Type

I've realized this lines has been added to web.config automatically:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

After defining the new `MIME Type` I've restarted website, restarted whole `IIS` service, I still get a `404 error` it is appreciated if someone could guide me how to debug the problem from this point.

---

### Tracing Log:

As suggested in comments I've enabled [Troubleshooting Failed Requests Using Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis):

```
Headers="Connection: close
Accept: 
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,
application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed- 
exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Comment: First, make sure that the file actually exists on requested path. Then, turn on Failed Request Tracing and check the logs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Where exactly does the `.apk` reside? Provide an example to the path you're requesting.

Comment: @haim770 I've updated my question. Now example path is in second paragraph.

Comment: Make sure that `<system.webServer>\<security>\<requestFiltering>\<fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true" />` is set (to *true*)

Comment: @haim770 `fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true"` didn't change anything. I've noticed there is `application/signed-exchange` in request header. Is it possible that if `.apk` file be unsigned I get a `404 error`?

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with the `Accept` header. Do you see the full YSOD (Yellow-screen-of-death)? Does it provide more data in the "Detailed Error Information" section? Like "Module", for example?

Comment: @haim770 In where? When I point to `http://example.com/Upload/App/a.apk` I don't see yellow screen of death. I see `HTTP ERROR 404`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My search over stackoverflow and google was wrong. My deployed project on `IIS` is a `.Net Core` website and it seems in `.Net Core` projects there is no need to add new `MIME Types` in `IIS` server. Instead `MIME Types` are handled in `Configure()` method inside `Startup.cs`

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings[".apk"] = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```